# Removing single quote on it's own in bash script without removing other single quotes?

Tags: bash, sed

I have file that has data that looks like this:

```
$table_prefix = 'wp_';
'
$more_stuff = 'ab_';
'
```

where randomly there is a single quote on a line by itself.  I'm struggling on how to remove this while not impacting the other quotes?

I've tried sed:

```
sed -i -z "s/'\n/""/g" wp-config.php
```

Looking for ' and newline and then replacing with nothing or I don't mind if it's even replaced with a space.

Comment: Do you want to leave the line empty, or delete the line?

Comment: either one would be fine, can you show me both? :)

Comment: In `awk` you can try like: `awk '!/^\047$/'`

Comment: `sed "/^'$/d" file`

Comment: What produced that data? I'd be much more confident about the data in the file if it weren't producing the stray quotes in the first place, instead of assuming that removing them after the fact is sufficient.

Comment: You probably have DOS line endings in your php file

Comment: how do I deal with DOS line endings?

Comment: Still they are there.  It's literally 4 of them, that if I manually remove them the file is fine.  I've tried removing the lines with awk and still they persist!

Comment: I don't see them when  I run this :   sudo < wp-config.php tr -d '\r'   but not sure how to save that back?

Comment: Try `sed -i 's/\r$//g' wp-config.php` and then `sed -i "/^'$/d" wp-config.php`.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -i "s/^'$//" wp-config.php
```

or

```
sed -i "/^'$/d" wp-config.php
```

(I advise you to try it without `-i` first, to make sure it does what you expect in your version of sed.)

Comment: For some reason those are not working for me

Comment: @user3486773: For some reason, your comment is not giving me enough information to resolve the problem. What happens when you try them without the `-i`?

Comment: it doesn't have any impact.  I have also tried to remove the lines with them using awk but that doensn't work.  I can remove the line above with with awk.  it's like it's a hidden quote mark or something

Comment: I don't see them when I run this sudo < wp-config.php tr -d '\r'  but not sure how to save that back?

Comment: @user3486773: I suspect you have some extra whitespace on those lines. You can use `"s/./X/g"` to turn every character into an X, and see how many there are. Or be brutal about it: `sed -i "/^'.*$/d" wp-config.php`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
sed -i 's/\r$//g' wp-config.php
sed -i "/^'$/d" wp-config.php
```

- `sed -i 's/\r$//g' wp-config.php` - removes all carriage return characters that have a line feed after them
- `sed -i "/^'$/d" wp-config.php` - removes all lines with standalone apostrophes.